# How to find check any changes has been made to an android activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have more than 30 fields in a layout including editing text and spinner. is there any **Logical** way that identifies that value of any has been changed without checking each field programmatically?

Comment: please elaborate on what exactly you wanted???

Comment: you really want to check while not checking? That sounds like some kind of magic. If I needed to do that, I'd have extended all controls to custom classes, and made that classes to message you that they are changed once they get changed. Or added listeners to them.

Answer (score 0):

the simples way is group your widgets. And add to your widgets unique `tag`. Then use single listener each group.
For example:

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher)
et2.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher)
et2.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher)
... etc
```

Or add widgets in array.

```
for(int i=0;i<ets.size();i++){
ets.get(i).addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
}

for(int i=0;spinners.size();i++){
spinners.get(0).setOnItemSelectedListener(myItemSelectedListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Git where you can make repositories and check any changes occurred to specific files